# Is it possible to relate a table on a pivot one with eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

These are my tables `many-to-many`:

`products` and `suppliers`, however I need to relate the pivot(product_supplier) to a table called `payment_supplier`.

[image]

**Product model**

```
 public function suppliers(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Supplier');
}
```

**Supplier model**

```
 public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
}
```

but I need to relate pivot product_supplier to payment_supplier table just like described on the diagram

Comment: Belongstomany is what you need

Comment: Do I need to create a model called ProductSupplier so I can relate it?

Comment: No, no need. Laravel guesses pivot table names!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you could use a pivot model.

```php
# Product Model
public function suppliers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Supplier::class)->using(ProductSupplier::class);
}
```

```php
# Supplier Model
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->using(ProductSupplier::class);
}
```

```php
# ProductSupplier Pivot Model
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class ProductSupplier extends Pivot
{
    public function payment_supplier()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PaymentSupplier::class);
    }
}
```

However, doing it like this has a big problem: You CANNOT eager load a pivot's relationships. Not without an override (or a package).

The other way to go about it is using `hasManyThrough`

```php
# Product Model
public function suppliers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Supplier::class)->using(ProductSupplier::class);
}

public function payment_suppliers()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(PaymentSupplier::class, ProductSupplier::class);
}
```

```php
# Supplier Model
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->using(ProductSupplier::class);
}

public function payment_suppliers()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(PaymentSupplier::class, ProductSupplier::class);
}
```

This gives you every PaymentSupplier for a single Supplier/Product, so you'll need to apply some kind of filtering.